# Failing to generate correct OAuth 1.0 signature with PHP

Tags: php, oauth, signature

I'm trying to use vanilla PHP to get some data from an API with oAuth 1.0 authorization. My code is below, the API keeps responding to it with code 401: Invalid signature. As far as I can see, the method for generating signature conforms with examples from documentation and from Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there perhaps a problem with my nonce?

```
const consumer_key = "20CECD28B41A458E9E328BB45C26EACB";
const consumer_secret = "F485B390C5854A69A8DA17554E689D03";
const token = "5F3C117598A14BE8B7136659AB2251C0";
const token_secret = "647E14C4F7EF4DA5AA119D5C60E95114";

function generateNonce($timestamp){
    $TimeReduced = substr($timestamp, 0, -2);
    $string = $TimeReduced;
    $hash = hash('sha1', $string, false);
    return $hash;
}

function generateSignature($request, $timestamp, $nonce){
  $base = $request['method']."&".rawurlencode($request['url'])."&"
      .rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=".rawurlencode(consumer_key)
      ."&oauth_nonce=".rawurlencode($nonce)
      ."&oauth_signature_method=".rawurlencode("HMAC-SHA1")
      ."&oauth_timestamp=". rawurlencode($timestamp)
      ."&oauth_token=".rawurlencode(token)
      ."&oauth_version=".rawurlencode("1.0"));

    $key = rawurlencode(consumer_secret).'&'.rawurlencode(token_secret);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', $base, $key, true));
    return $signature;
}

$ch = curl_init();

$request = array();
$request['url'] = 'https://someniceapi.com';
$request['method'] = 'GET';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request['method']);

$timestamp = time();
$nonce = generateNonce($timestamp);
$signature = generateSignature($request, $timestamp, $nonce);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.consumer_key.'",oauth_token="'.token.'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature='.$signature.'",oauth_timestamp="'.$timestamp.'",oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.'",oauth_version="1.0"';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was the missing " before signature value. Such a basic error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base64-encode the hash in its "lower-case hexits" form, not its binary form.

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', $base, $key, true));
```

hash_hmac with fourth parameter set to true, gets you the binary form.

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', $base, $key));
```

is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your expert help but I'm still getting "401: Signature invalid" from the API

Comment: @PaulJK In your Authorization header, `,oauth_signature='.$signature.'",` - there seems to be a `"` missing before the value here.

Comment: Excellent catch, thank you. I fixed it but the response is stil the same. This is sample signature with timestamp and nonce that I'm generating: `oauth_signature="MGQ0Mjk4YjA1NzkwNjEzODMyZmU3NWE5MjNiMjU4M2QyZmNjOTNjMg==",oauth_timestamp="1706530930",oauth_nonce="d16196d4a62f43bc8394832c8c83a40b6becfe8a"`

Comment: Google used to provide a test tool for this, they don't any more, but it is still available via the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160430150356/https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html Suggest you input all your values there, and then check if the parts match what you are generating.

Comment: Using their tool, I notice that the input URL value `https://someniceapi.com` automatically gets a trailing slash added in the signature base string. So try and add that in your code as well, `$request['url'] = 'https://someniceapi.com/';`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the URL. I've confirmed that the signature base string I'm generating is 100% identical to the one generated in the tool, it's just the resulting signature that's different. Edit: I've added back the "true" parameter to hash_hmac and now I'm getting identical signature as with the tool.

Comment: Surprises me (that last edit), because for example https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html#signature also explicitly shows `hash_hmac` used _without_ the third parameter set.